# Double cannot be dereferenced

Tags: java

### Question

What might be the cause of my problem and how do I solve it:

My program crashes if a value *other than a double* is entered by the user.

### Program body

```
public class Annual
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner percent = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter annual sales:");
        double yearly = percent.nextInt();
        double T = 50000;
        double Amt;
        if (yearly.matches("[0-9]+") && yearly.length() > 2 && yearly.length() <= 8)
        {
            double YrPrcnt = yearly * .05;
            Amt = T + YrPrcnt;
            System.out.print("The Annual Payrate for employee is:");
            System.out.print(Amt);
        }
    }
}
```

### Error messages

"*double cannot be dereferenced*" and "*illegal start of expression*"

### What I've tried

Simplest method: check if the user input is a number and provide an error message if so.

### System info

I am coding this in NetBeans 7.2, and am new to Java.

Comment: The `nextInt()` function of `Scanner` will throw an exception if the next input is not a number. You should either be catching the possible exception (and skip trying to test whether it's a number) or you should be reading the next token as a `String` instead of an `int`.

Comment: Tedd Hopp, I am not sure what you mean, "The nextInt() function of Scanner will throw an exception if the next input is not a number." Are you saying that the Scanner has some built in error detection?? Because I know that it is not preventing the program from crashing if someone enters anything except a number at the prompt. So, if Scanner is supposed to be watching this, it is NOT!!

Comment: From [the docs for `nextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()): "Throws `InputMismatchException` - if the next token does not match the Integer regular expression, or is out of range". I just tested this and it indeed works. Since you aren't catching `InputMismatchException`, you program would indeed crash. But how are you crashing when it won't even compile?

Comment: the only relevant stuff here is @Perception. The OP needs to learn what a compilation error is and how to read it.

Answer (score 2):

```
yearly.matches
```

`double` (yearly) is primitive type, you can't call method (matches (or) any) on primitive.

To check whether input is range, you need to use greater than and less than operators.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (yearly.matches("[0-9]+") && yearly.length() > 2 && yearly.length() <= 8)
```

You are treating `yearly` to be a String here. If that's your intention, then read the user input into a String, perform your checks on that string and convert it into double using `Double.parseDouble()` method.